# Sass - find maximum value of list

Tags: list, sass

Seems like this should be easy. How do I get the min/max values from a list using sass?

```
$max-value: max(10, 20, 30); // returns 30

$list: 10, 20, 30;
$max-value: max($list); // Syntax error: (10, 20, 30) is not a number for `max'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
$max-value: max($list...);
```